How to Recover Encrypted Files Recovered by PhotoRec on Linux Mint
I am actually a windows user and had many files on it which I never encrypted. I installed linux mint while checking "encrypt home directory" and formatted my drive. Then I ran photorec to recover the files and it gave my 6000 recup_dir files (e.g., recupdir_1, recupdir_2, ..., recupdir_6000), each with 500 ecryptfs files. My questions are

When I never encrypted any files, why did it give me ecryptfs files from windows.
What should be the passphrase? My current home directory passphrase or what?
I tried running "ecryptfs-recover-private" with exact location of one of my folder but instead of mounting decrypted folder, it mounted whole home directory with a lock logo on it in /temp

Please tell me what should I do. I also don't know how to use linux properly as I just installed it.

So you formatted your drive and then encrypted the entire drive?  File recovery in that situation will not be possible. You might have been able to recovery files before you encrypted the entire drive, file recovery after you format a drive, is entirely dependant on what data is written to the disk.

You state "I installed linux mint while checking "encrypt home directory" and formatted my drive. " Do you mean the entire drive? Then you might be able to recover some files using a commercial data recovery service... if it's worth the expense. Stop using the drive, if you hope to have any chance of recovery.

I ran phtorec and it already has recovered 187 gb files out of my 227 gb hard disk. Did I lost it now forever?
